# How to change contents of a webpage without refreshing?

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, ajax, flask

I'm trying to make an application with flask. This is part of my code:

**base.html**

```
<div id= "contents">
<button onclick="changeContents()">Click me</button>
{% block text %}{% endblock %}
</div>

<script>
  function changeContents() {
    var xhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
    xhttp.open("GET", "index", true);
    xhttp.onreadystatechange = function() {
      if (xhttp.readyState == 4 && xhttp.status == 200) {
      document.getElementById("contents").innerHTML = xhttp.responseText;
     }
    }
    xhttp.send();
  }
</script>
```

**index.html**

```
{% extends "base.html" %}

{% block text %}
<p>Hello</p>
{% endblock %}
```

What happens is the `<div id = "contents">` gets replaced with the **entire** webpage, so I have a webpage within a webpage. I thought of using

`document.getElementById("contents").innerHTML = '<object type="text/html" data="index" ></object>';`

and it also did the same thing, but a smaller page within the page. Why is it doing this? Are there simple solutions using plain javascript or jQuery?

**Edit:**

Instead of

```
document.getElementById("contents").innerHTML = xhttp.responseText;
```

I've removed the entire webpage and just wrote

```
document.body.innerHTML = xhttp.responseText;
```

It works but I'm pretty sure this is bad practice..

Comment: What happens is the <div id = "contents"> gets replaced with the entire webpage, so I have a webpage within a webpage. This exactly what is should be doing so nothing wrong here. what you need to do is either a) detect ajax call at server and only send the information you need or b) search through xhttp.responseText and extract the part you need.

Comment: @Syed I'm not too adept with ajax. I can't really find a solution for the second option..

Comment: Check my answer I have tried to exemplify it as possible.

Answer (score 0):

Here is an bit of code snippet that might work for you.

1. your XMLHttpRequest is working fine and there is a reponseText too, so all good
2. Next we need to parse the response text into html using  DOMParser()
3. Then we search through that parsed html referenced via variable i.e. instead of document.getElementById we use the variable.getElementById
4. Then extract what you need
5. Then copy outerHTML of the extracted element to the innerHTML of the div we want changed.

```js
function chnagehtml(){

var button =  document.getElementById('changeme');
var response = '<html><head></head><body><div id="a">hellow</div> <div id="b">hellow</div></body></html>';

var parser = new DOMParser();


var parsedDoc = parser.parseFromString(response, "text/html");
var iJustWantDiv = parsedDoc.getElementById('a'); 
console.log(iJustWantDiv);
button.innerHTML = iJustWantDiv.outerHTML;


}
```

```html
<div id="changeme">Iam empty</div>
<button id="button" onclick='chnagehtml();'>get html</button>
```

So in your code could go something like this;

```
if (xhttp.readyState == 4 && xhttp.status == 200) {


var parser = new DOMParser();


var parsedDoc = parser.parseFromString(xhttp.responseText, "text/html");
var iJustWantDiv = parsedDoc.getElementById('a'); 

document.getElementById("contents").innerHTML = iJustWantDiv.outerHTML;
     }
```

Comment: Almost worked. My javascript near the end of ```<body>``` don't work. I don't get it, I'm only changing ```<div>``` which is inside ```<body>```. Everything else works fine though, including the code inside ```<body>``` that's outside of the ```<div>``` and the code inside my ```<head>``` tags.

Comment: are you trying to load new JS via ajax or is it core JS thats already in body? If you are trying to load new js like div or if there is any JS parsed and in jected via above examples that particular piece of code wont work.